# Dynamically change a banner size on changing the browser window using Jquery

Tags: jquery, resize

I came up with this solution that works well, except I have to refresh the screen to change the banner size.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var wi = $("#containingDiv").width();
    var iw = $(document).width();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var iw = $(document).width();
        $('#test b').html(iw);
        $(window).resize(function () {
            iw = $(document).width();
            $('#test b').html(iw);
            wi = $("#containingDiv").width();
            wi = Math.round(iw * .6);
            $('#test1 b').html(wi);
            $("#s1").css('width',wi);
            $("#s2").css('width',wi);
            $("#s3").css('width',wi);
            $("#s4").css('width',wi);
            $("#s5").css('width',wi);
            $("#s6").css('width',wi);
            $("#s7").css('width',wi);
            $("#s8").css('width',wi);


        });
        $('#allinone_bannerRotator_classic').allinone_bannerRotator({
            skin: 'classic',
            width: wi,
            height: wi /2,
            responsive: true,
            responsiveRelativeToBrowser: true,
            animationTime: 0.5,
            width100Proc: false,
            autoHideBottomNav: true,
            showPreviewThumbs: false,
            showNavArrows: false,
            showBottomNav: false,
            autoHideNavArrows: true,
            loop: true,
            enableTouchScreen: true,
            showCircleTimer: false,
            autoPlay: 4,
            resizeImages: true,
            defaultEffect: 'fade'
        });

        ////$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        ////    mode: 'fade',
        ////    captions: true
        ////});
    });
</script>
```

First I get the div width where I have placed the banner, and get the document width, then I scale the images and the banner.  I tried to put the banner script inside the window resize, unfortunately it did not work, could not see the images.  I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First, you you should put your resize function next to the ready function, not inside.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Stuffs here
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    //Stuffs here
});
```

And there will be a `.refresh()` function for your allinone_bannerRotator pluggin.

So, on ready, you initialize your pluggin, on resize, you set new options (width), and then refresh.
Read the pluggin's documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add refresh to the banner script but did not work.  Got this error Object doesn't support property or method 'refresh'

Comment: I don't know this pluggin. The only one i found is a licenced one, and do not display the doc until you buy it, so i can't say if 'refresh' exist for this pluggin.

Comment: I did buy it and could not find anything related to refresh.  100Proc true will make the banner full page, I just need it to be 60% inside DIV.  Thanks